# C# chart secondary axis type minimum values and interval problems

Tags: c#, charts, intervals

I got chart with one series, and Y is set to secondary to show its values on axis on right side, not left. Before this i changed minimum values `Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 100;` and it worked, after i add this line: `g_series.YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;` it doesnt, it always stays 0 on my form (its remains 100 but on chart it starts from 0).

Also, this worked `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 10;` and after i change type on secondary it doesnt. If i comment this `g_series.YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;` all intervals of Yaxis and minimum values works fine, but i need those values on axis displayed on right side, and only known method is to change iths type on secondary.

How can i keep them on right with wokring min values and intervals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not set the primary to have secondary properties, but would just go directly to Y2. For example:

```
ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Interval = 1;
```

You can either hide or simply not declare the primary axis.